# Magick.NET set PSD Blendmode

Tags: c#, imagemagick, magick.net, imagemagick.net

I'm trying to create a psd file with Magick.NET. I could not find any information about wether it's possible to set the Blendmode for a specific layer to Multiply. Can anyone help me? This is my code:

```
MagickImageCollection c = new MagickImageCollection();
MagickImage imgBase = new MagickImage(img);
c.Add(imgBase);
c.Add(imgDiffuse);
c.Add(imgAO);
c.Write("...destinationPath.psd");
```

I now want the "imgAO" Layer to be set to Multiply with an opacity of 80%. is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. Quite easy actually. Just do  `imgAO.Compose = CompositeOperator.Multiply;` before adding it to the Collection. Now the only thing left is controling the opacity of the individual layers, but I don't think this is possible.